Slurm controller and compute node connectivity issue on single node server
I have installed SLURM on a single-node server system. I could successfully install SLURM and run both the controller and compute node daemon on the server. However, sinfo ended up with the following error:
sinfo: error: resolve_ctls_from_dns_srv: res_nsearch error: Unknown host
sinfo: error: fetch_config: DNS SRV lookup failed
sinfo: error: _establish_config_source: failed to fetch config
sinfo: fatal: Could not establish a configuration source

Can anyone here help to resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance!

This error message indicates that configless mode is activated but not configured. With a single node, though, configless mode is not needed, as the slurm.conf file must exist for the controller process to start. The reason could be then, that the slurm.conf file is not readable by the user running the sinfo command. Can you try

running sinfo as root, or
making sure the permissions are 644 for /etc/slurm/slurm.conf?

